# Can I hide Skype conversations permanently?

Tags: skype, privacy

I know one can hide conversations in skype, but they always come back when you get another message from it. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Skype does not allow us to do so. You can only hide temporarily or just delete it.

Comment: @TimBerty There are no plugins or the like?

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing like you asked.